# Need help for sql query (split and merge items)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table A:

```
   dateTime             content             code
============================================================
20010101 13:00          content1           1|A|4
20010101 13:50          content2           2|B|4
20010102 19:00          content3           29|C
```

Table B(Expected output):

```
dateTime         code         content
===========================================
20010101           1          content1
20010101           2          content2
20010101           4        content1;content2
20010102           29         content3
```

I need a sql query to get `Table B` from `Table A`. Requirement:

1. Split the `code` by delimiter `|`. And at the same time, only keep number `code`, ignoring all character `code`.
2. Ignore hour & minute. Merge items with the same `dateTime` and `code`.
3. Use  `;` to separate `content` with the same `dateTime` and `code`.
4. `order by dateTime, code`, which I'm able to solve by myself : )

Comment: Sigh... Never ever store data as ; separated items.

Comment: Well, you requirements are clear. But what have you tried by yourself? Or is it just "write code for me" request?

Comment: @GordonLinoff expected result is TableB as far as I can see from question.

Comment: @Andy Korneyev . I'm a noob to sql query. So it's a "write code for me"  question... Thanks.

Comment: interesting homework :)

Comment: post the  Expected output  @lotterier

Comment: Expected output is `Table B`

Comment: Post the expected output

Comment: what kind of requirement is this why code column is stored like that @lotterier

Comment: @mohan111 `Table A` is a table from a commercial database. We buy their data. They just provide the data in that way...

Comment: You should make the title more descriptive. That may get you back from the -1 score.

Comment: Why oh why do you want to take one version of denormalized data and change it to a different form of denormalized data. This is a mess. Look at normalizing this so you don't violate 1NF by storing multiple values in a single intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at other posts that had similar problems I came up with this: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3d69/6)

```
with tmp(mydate, content, CodeItem, code) as (
select mydate, content, LEFT(code, CHARINDEX('|',code+'|')-1),
    STUFF(code, 1, CHARINDEX('|',code+'|'), '')
from A
union all
select mydate, content, LEFT(code, CHARINDEX('|',code+'|')-1),
    STUFF(code, 1, CHARINDEX('|',code+'|'), '')
from tmp
where code > ''
)
select Convert(date,mydate), content, codeItem
from tmp
where isnumeric(codeItem) = 1
order by mydate
```

EDIT: now with the concatenated contents (this might just be the most complicated sql I've ever written) [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5ac1/16)

```
with tmp(mydate, content, CodeItem, code) as (
select mydate, content, LEFT(code, CHARINDEX('|',code+'|')-1),
    STUFF(code, 1, CHARINDEX('|',code+'|'), '')
from A
union all
select mydate, content, LEFT(code, CHARINDEX('|',code+'|')-1),
    STUFF(code, 1, CHARINDEX('|',code+'|'), '')
from tmp
where code > ''
)
select distinct Convert(date,t1.mydate) AS my_date, t1.codeItem,
 contents = STUFF((
          select concat(',' , t2.content)
          from tmp t2
          where t1.mydate = t2.mydate AND t1.codeItem = t2.codeItem
   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from tmp t1
where isnumeric(codeItem) = 1
order by my_date
```

NOTE: you might need to change the column where the codes are saved to a varchar(max) column if it's not already that because this doesn't seem to work otherwise

Comment: Doesn't meet the third requirement.  I think one more line with the `STUFF` operator will get you there though.

Comment: ah right, stepped over the 3rd one, you have no idea how long it took me to get this, I'll probably need another 20 minutes :p

Comment: scratch 20 minutes, I'm gonna need more time and sqlfiddle is down so I can't do any tests